# I'm trying to export a spread but it is not working

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am trying to export a two page spread in indesign to png so i can put it in a mockup in photoshop. However whenever I export it, it justs exports the first cover page.

Edit: Heres a picture

[image]

Edit 2: Here's the pages box

[image]

Comment: Is your document only 2 pages or more?

Comment: 1 spread (2 pages side by side) and 1 cover page

Comment: What you're doing should be right. I suspect an issue with the document itself. Sections could be defined which could interfere with the page numbering. Can we see a screenshot that shows all your pages zoomed out AND the Pages panel open? Your current screenshot looks like there's only 2 pages, eg. not enough scroll to allow for a third page. Assuming the cover page is missing from this screenshot?

Comment: Added pages box, I don't know how to show all pages on the screen sorry

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is an old question, but just in case someone has the same issue:

You've designed your spread in A-Master instead of an actual page.
In "pages" double click on A-Master and cut that content out of there. Then double click on your cover page, add two new pages and paste your content there. Then try exporting :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical case of an 'unclear question'. You appear to have a misunderstanding of what you are working with (probably a template) and/or the way InDesign works:

- your document only has 1 page, not 3 pages. this 1 page appears to be the 'cover'
- what you thought was the other 2 pages is actually set up as a double master page. i won't go into the differences between these here. do some research on your own on pages/master pages and try to understand your document

The quick fix:

- right click your only page in the 'Pages' panel (the thumbnail with a '2' below it in your second image). Choose 'Numbering & Section Options' and type '1' in the 'Start Page numbering at' field
- add 2 new pages in your document after the existing page and make this use the existing A-Master
- then you should really have 3 pages
- then try to re-export as you initially tried. it should work now

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have added the pages but now it makes the cover and and second page a spread and the third page on its own? Mind telling me how to change it. You guessed it, it's my first time using inDesign

Comment: I have updated my answer with a new first bullet that should resolve this. If you feel this answers your question try clicking the _check_ icon and the _up_ arrow next to my answer above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to specifically export as *spreads*:

- File > Export
- Select "png" from the "save as type" dropdown
- Save
- In the window that opens (Export PNG) select "spreads"

Note: You could also export as pdf (again, spreads). That more options, and you can drag a pdf straight into Photoshop.

Comment: I tried that before and now again, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: What version of InDesign do you have? And did you try the PDF export as well? Are you selecting all pages in the export dialogue? Perhaps a screen shot of the export dialogue would help.

Comment: I have the latest. Yes I have tried both. Yes I think I am selecting them all. I'll get a screen cap now.

Comment: I  just set up a test document myself. Five pages. A cover page and two spreads. I did the export as above and it made three png files. Perhaps (long shot) you are literally not seeing the other two png files? These three files has one (non-spread obviously) A4 cover, and two "double" A4 spreads. If this doesn't work for you I can only think it's a program error :( Please let me know! :)

Comment: No, only the one haha! I needed to get it out so I ended up just using the snipping tool! wish i did not have too. I'd still like to know what's wrong for future reference.